# Address Public Private key verification

Tags: cryptography

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but when a bitcoin client wishes to send funds to an address, does the bitcoin protocol force the client to verify that the address has a corresponding private key?

For example, I am given an address and I want to send a btc to this address, before I am allowed to authorize this transaction does the bitcoin protocol force me to verify that the address can decrypt a message encrypted from its public key?

Comment: Transactions are not encrypted.  They do use cryptographic signed messages though.

Comment: I'm aware that transactions are not encrypted but the address we send money to is part of a public private key pair. One could verify that the address is legitimate by requiring the receiver to encrypt and decrypt a test message with his pub-pri keypair

Comment: The checksum scheme seems to fail for one in four billion addresses. Yes this is sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no enforcement that a private key exists.

However, due to a Bitcoin address including a checksum, it is very unlikely for the client to create a transaction when for an address with a typo, paste error, or other erroneous data.  There are addresses that will pass the checksum test in which, presumably, no private key exists. [1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE) is, in all likelihood, one such address.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the fast answer

Comment: Also, that would mean you would need tons of additional information to form a transaction, including the public key which you currently don't need. It would kind of defeat the whole point of addresses.